# Executing UDF ( User Defined function ) containing a Node module in Cosmos Db

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, node-modules, user-defined-functions

I have created a UDF function to process some content based on dates in Azure cosmos database. The function looks like below

```
  
  function userDefinedFunction(array,dateString){
    var moment = require('moment');
    const startDate = moment(dateString);
    const endDate = moment(dateString).add(1,'days');
    // filter the array by the dates and return a value
   
  }
```

When the above UDF is used inside a query the following error message is thrown .

`Encountered exception while executing Javascript. Exception = ReferenceError: 'require' is not defined`

This error is seemed to be an error orginating from incorrect import of the **moment node module**.

i have already tried checking on the [microsoft offcial docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/udfs) about the UDFs and using of node module inside UDF.

I tried surfing through the internet about this  issue,  but both the methods did not provide me with satisfactory answer.

so i would like to know how to import a node module and use it inside an UDF function . Thanks a lot in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing modules is not supported for any of the service-side features including stored procedures, triggers and user-defined functions.

This is not currently documented. Will ask for this to be updated.

Comment: thanks @mark-brown for the prompt feedback